# Change Value of nested node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This seems like a simple question but I can't seem to get started on a working solution. The final goal is to change the value of the `ConstantValue` element highlighted below.  My strategy is to find the `Component` node and drill down from there.  The problem is that keep returning a null and I'm not sure why.  Below is the code I'm using a the xml I'm using.  Any hints would be great.

```
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
        var items = xmlDoc.Descendants("Component")
                            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "axesInterface")
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Engineering version="V17" />
  <DocumentInfo> 
  </DocumentInfo>
  <SW.Blocks.FB ID="0">
    <AttributeList>     
      <Interface><Sections></Sections></Interface>
      <MemoryLayout>Optimized</MemoryLayout>
      <MemoryReserve>100</MemoryReserve>
      <Name>EM00_CM01_Warp1</Name>
      <Number>31650</Number>
      <ProgrammingLanguage>LAD</ProgrammingLanguage>
      <SetENOAutomatically>false</SetENOAutomatically>
    </AttributeList>
    <ObjectList>    
      <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="4" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
        <AttributeList>
          <NetworkSource>
            <FlgNet xmlns="http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/NetworkSource/FlgNet/v4">
                <Parts>    
                  <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="27">
                    <Symbol>
                      <Component Name="HMIAxisCtrl_Interface" />
                      <Component Name="axesInterface" AccessModifier="Array">
                        <Access Scope="LiteralConstant">
                          <Constant>
                            <ConstantType>DInt</ConstantType>
                            <ConstantValue>0</ConstantValue>
                          </Constant>
                        </Access>
                      </Component>
                    </Symbol>
                  </Access>   
                </Parts>
            </FlgNet>
          </NetworkSource>         
        </AttributeList>     
      </SW.Blocks.CompileUnit>       
    </ObjectList>
  </SW.Blocks.FB>
</Document>
```

Comment: You are more likely to get a response if you include well-formed XML that illustrates what you are trying to do (**as text**, formatted as _code_).  That way, folks can grab your XML and play with it.  Including code (XML isn't quite code, but it's close enough) as text is always way better than as a picture

Comment: You need to handle the namespace on the FlgNet element like @Charlieface does in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your XML example, you can simply get specified node with this piece of code at any depth:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
XElement node = xmlDoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ConstantValue");
node.Value = "New value";
xmlDoc.Save(somewhere);
```

If there may be multiple nodes with `"ConstantValue"` name - then just replace `FirstOrDefault` with `Where` and work with filtered by names `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Why it isn't find by `x.Name == "ConstantValue"`:

[image]

EDIT: added samples.

```
// That's your parent node
var componentNode = xmlDoc.Descendants()
                          .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Component" 
                                   && (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "axesInterface");
// Get first ConstantValue node from parent Component node
var constantValueNode = componentNode.Descendants()
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ConstantValue");
// or get all ConstantValue nodes from parent Component node
var constantValueNodes = componentNode.Descendants()
                                     .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ConstantValue");

if (constantValueNode is XElement)
    constantValueNode.Value = "New value";
```

You can create extension method to get parent node by specifying level:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static XElement GetParentNode(this XElement element, int parentLevel)
    {
        XElement node = element.Parent;

        for (int i = 0; i < parentLevel; i++)
            node = node.Parent;

        return node;
    }
}
```

In your example, `var parent = constantValueNode.GetParentNode(2);` will return Component node (with attribute `Name="axesInterface"`). `var parent = constantValueNode.GetParentNode(12);` will return root "Document" node.

Comment: great solution. the problem is the code I gave is a much simpler version to keep it short.  There are many `ConstantValue` nodes.  Is it possible to specifiy a parent node... or even better a parent of a  parent .  For example I could see the `ConstantValue` that belonged to  a speific  component (2 levels up in the xml example)?

Comment: @mrsargent, check please I edited answer and added some code at end. You can get **any** node at **any** depth through `Descendants()` and `x.Name.LocalName = "YouNodeName"`. Or I do not undestand what you asking for :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use XQuery to get the correct node:

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

//

var nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nm.AddNamespace("sm", "http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/NetworkSource/FlgNet/v4");

var node = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(@"//sm:Access[@Scope=""LiteralConstant""]/sm:Constant/sm:ConstantValue", nm);

node.Value = "Something Else";
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rpgfUU)

For multiple nodes, change `XPathSelectElement` to `XPathSelectElements`

Comment: thanks.  this is a good option.